# Merge Bitmap with standard Java

Tags: java, graphics, bitmap

i've found lots of implementation on how to merge bitmpaps, now i'm trying to do the same, but without Android jars as every attempt i've seen before.

I have 16 bitmaps images of 128*128 px.

I need to merge them vertically...what's resulting me is a completely black bmp 128x128*16...so it doesn't work.

This is what i've done so far:

Reading all the Bmps which are 128*128 px tiles into an array of BufferedImage:

```
BufferedImage[] input = new BufferedImage[16];   
        int counter = 0;
        for(File f: new File(fixBmpPathFolder).listFiles()){
            System.out.println(f.getAbsolutePath() + " loaded!");
            int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;

            input[counter]  =  new BufferedImage(ImageIO.read( f ).getWidth(null), ImageIO.read( f ).getHeight(null), type); 
            counter++;
        } 
        mergeAndSave(input);
```

And here the mergeAndSave method:

```
   public static void mergeAndSave(BufferedImage input[]) throws IOException {   
        BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(128, 128*input.length, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY);
        Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();
        int y = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ) { //replaced by input.length
            g.drawImage( input[i],0,y,null); 
            y += 128;
        }   
        g.dispose(); 
        ImageIO.write(bimage, "BMP", new FileOutputStream(getFileResultAbsoluteName())); 
    }
```

Now i've made a similar attempt for png, which works fine, now after some researches i've noticed that could work for bmps too, setting properly the type integer enum of buffered result image.

I've run this code, for a single bmp and it work, just read and save in another place.

For my needs the file has to be binary type result.

thanks!

EDIT: Sorry guys i've leaved last experiment value on single loop, but i've tried obviously with a complete loop of the images.
Now i know this code is not fantastic, but it's only a simple scratch to take the goal.
Merge them vertically means that i've got 16 bitmap of same dimensions (128*128), and i would like to get a resulting bitmap which would be the join of the starting 16, where they are one on top of each other.

Comment: So what the question is ? )

Comment: What do you mean with *merge them vertically*.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your `for` loop, where you have hardcoded the bound of `1`, you of course need to replace this by `input.length`.

Furthermore I've also replaced the construction of the `BufferedImage` with `128*input.length` instead of `128*16`, since this would imply you hardcoded `16` images.

Finally I renamed `hcount` to `y`, since this is a more semantical name.

```
public static void mergeAndSave(BufferedImage input[]) throws IOException {  
    int type = BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY;
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(128, 128*input.length, type);
    Graphics g = bimage.createGraphics();
    int y = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i < input.length; i++ ) { //replaced by input.length
        g.drawImage( input[i],0,y,null); 
        y += 128;
    }   
    g.dispose(); 
    ImageIO.write(bimage, "BMP", new FileOutputStream(getFileResultAbsoluteName())); 
}
```

On the other hand however, I think this code is not very well constructed. It makes a lot of assumptions about the images. This makes the code almost **not reusable**, one of the main aspects of good code:

- You assume all images have the same size of 128x128, instead you can drop this constraint;
- You hardcode a lot of constants.

Perhaps you should consider making your code more generic so you can solve more problems with it.

Comment: I've explained better, anyway this code made same of what i've done so far and is not the answer...

Comment: @Mark: I've made a small error in the first version, if you use the new version, I get the images that are "merged" in the resulting picture...

Comment: it doesn't. If u want u can use my images, i've uploaded them here:http://www.filedropper.com/bs2originalfix